# Dynamic dropdown doesn't get selected the second time using cypress

Tags: cypress

I am new to cypress and trying to select a dropdown value from a dynamic list.
The below snippet of code works fine for the selection of dropdown first time.
It doesn't work for the second time. can you suggest, what is the problem with this code?

```
Cypress.Commands.add("selectValue", (valuetoSelect) => {

    cy.get(locators.selectDropdown).click()
    .then(() => {
        cy.get(locators.selectDropdown).type(valuetoSelect).wait(500)
            .get(locators.selectoption).each(($els) => {
               
                if ($els.text().trim() == "valuetoSelect") {
                    cy.wait(500);
                    cy.wrap($els).click();
                }
            })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a typo,

```js
if ($els.text().trim() == "valuetoSelect") {
```

should be

```js
if ($els.text().trim() === valuetoSelect) {
```

The shortest code for this is

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("selectValue", (valuetoSelect) => {

  cy.get(locators.selectDropdown).click()            // open dropdown
  cy.contains(locators.selectoption, valuetoSelect)  // select option with valuetoSelect
    .click()
})
```